# MVVM with realm: Passing Realm-results across threads?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, mvvm, realm

Using Xcode-8.2.1, Swift-3.0.2, RealmSwift-2.2.0, iOS-Simulator-10:

I try applying the MVVM pattern ([explained by Steve Scott here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VojuJpUuE8)) using Realm.

Everything works until the moment (inside the VIEW-part - see below) where I try to access a viewmodel-property. It says: `Realm accessed from incorrect thread`

How could I still make the MVVM-pattern do its job of separating model, view-model and view but, on the same time, get thread-safety with realm ?

Is there a way to make Realm-results (i.e. `Results<BalancesDataEntry>`) being passed across threads ??

Here is my code:
(the issue happens at the very bottom, inside the View-part)

```
// REALM-OBJECT:

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class BalancesDataEntry: Object {

    dynamic var category: String = ""
    dynamic var index: Int = 0  
}
```

MODEL:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MVVMCBalancesModel: BalancesModel
{

    fileprivate var entries = [BalancesDataEntry]()
    let realm = try! Realm()

    init() {
        self.createDataEntries()
    }

    fileprivate func createDataEntries() {

        let myBalance = BalancesDataEntry()
        myBalance.index = 0
        myBalance.category = "Love"

        try! self.realm.write {

            self.realm.deleteAll()
            self.realm.add(myBalance)
        }
    }

    func getEntries(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ entries: [BalancesDataEntry]) -> Void)
    {
        // Simulate Aysnchronous data access
        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            let realmThread = try! Realm()
            let returnArray: [BalancesDataEntry] = Array(realmThread.objects(BalancesDataEntry.self))
            completionHandler(returnArray)
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW-MODEL:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MVVMCBalancesViewModel: BalancesViewModel
{
    weak var viewDelegate: BalancesViewModelViewDelegate?
    weak var coordinatorDelegate: BalancesViewModelCoordinatorDelegate?

    fileprivate var entries: [BalancesDataEntry]? {
        didSet {
            viewDelegate?.entriesDidChange(viewModel: self)
        }
    }

    var model: BalancesModel? {
        didSet {
            entries = nil;
            model?.getEntries({ (myEntries) in
                self.entries = myEntries
            })
        }
    }

    var title: String {
        return "My Balances"
    }

    var numberOfEntries: Int {
        if let entries = entries {
            return entries.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func entryAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> BalancesDataEntry?
    {
        if let entries = entries , entries.count > index {

            return entries[index]
        }
        return nil
    }

    func useEntryAtIndex(_ index: Int)
    {
        if let entries = entries, let coordinatorDelegate = coordinatorDelegate  , index < entries.count {
            coordinatorDelegate.balancesViewModelDidSelectData(self, data: entries[index])
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
import UIKit

class MVVMCBalancesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1Outlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2Outlet: UILabel!

   var viewModel: BalancesViewModel? {
        willSet {
            viewModel?.viewDelegate = nil
        }
        didSet {
            viewModel?.viewDelegate = self
            refreshDisplay()
        }
    }

   var isLoaded: Bool = false

   func refreshDisplay()
   {
        if let viewModel = viewModel , isLoaded {

            // !!!!!!! HERE IS THE ISSUE: Realm accessed from incorrect thread !!!!
            self.label1Outlet.text = viewModel.entryAtIndex(0)?.category
            self.label2Outlet.text = viewModel.entryAtIndex(1)?.category
        } else {

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        isLoaded = true
        refreshDisplay();
    }

}

extension MVVMCBalancesViewController: BalancesViewModelViewDelegate
{
    func entriesDidChange(viewModel: BalancesViewModel)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the problem is that you are copying data out of Realm every time to force the asynchronousness, which is quite unnecessary as the query results are already being updated asynchronously. You could just do the query once and store the Results object in your model object. Then you could return this directly from your `getEntries()` method and it would always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ThreadSafeReference`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.4.2/api/Classes/ThreadSafeReference.html) to pass Realm's thread-confined types (`Object`, `Results`, `List`, `LinkingObjects`) to a different thread. The documentation's section on [Passing Instances Across Threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#passing-instances-across-threads) contains this example of passing a single instance of an `Object` subclass across threads:

```
let person = Person(name: "Jane")
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(person)
}
let personRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: person)
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  guard let person = realm.resolve(personRef) else {
    return // person was deleted
  }
  try! realm.write {
    person.name = "Jane Doe"
  }
}
```

It can be used similarly for `Results`.

Comment: Interesting concept! I will have a closer look at it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround (see below): Maybe you have better solutions - please let me know!

Here is my [github-code realm_mvvm_c on github](https://github.com/korners/realm_mvvm_c.git)

After introducing a new protocol and making (pretty much everything) conform to it, things worked out.

Here is the protocol called DataEntry:

```
import Foundation

protocol DataEntry: class {

    var idx: Int { get set }
    var category: String { get set }
}
```

Now, make everything conform to it, such as

--> the realm object (i.e. `class BalancesDataEntry: Object, DataEntry {...`)

--> the getEntries return value (i.e. `func getEntries(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ entries: [DataEntry]) -> Void)`)

--> the View-Model's entries (i.e. `fileprivate var entries: [DataEntry]? {..`)

--> all the corresponding Model- and View-Model protocols also need the DataEntry datatype (see git-repo for complete picture)

After that, it was enough to change the completion-handler return-array of the MODEL's method `getEntries(..)` to a newly created object-instance (ie. DataEntryDub) that is keept conform to the DataEntry protocol:

```
func getEntries(_ completionHandler: @escaping (_ entries: [DataEntry]) -> Void)
{
    // Simulate Aysnchronous data access
    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        let realmThread = try! Realm()

        class DataEntryDub: DataEntry {

            var idx: Int
            var category: String

            init(idx: Int, category: String) {
                self.idx = idx
                self.category = category
            }
        }

        var returnArray = [DataEntry]()
        for entry in realmThread.objects(BalancesDataEntry.self) {
             returnArray.append(DataEntryDub(idx: entry.idx, category: entry.category))
        }
        completionHandler(returnArray)
    }
}
```

Here is my [github-code realm_mvvm_c on github](https://github.com/korners/realm_mvvm_c.git)